# wp_enqueue_style is not working with a theme

Tags: wordpress

I have in stock html template.Сan't run styles in functions.php file

example from html template

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Перевозки в Израиле</title>
    <link href="<?= bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="<?= bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/css/template.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="<?= bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/css/icomoon.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="<?= bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/modules/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="<?= bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/modules/slick/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="<?= bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/modules/Magnific-Popup/magnific-popup.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="<?= bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/modules/vertical-timeline/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700%7COpen+Sans:100,300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="<?= bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/modules/revolution/fonts/pe-icon-7-stroke/css/pe-icon-7-stroke.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
    <link href="<?= bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/modules/revolution/fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
    <link href="<?= bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/modules/revolution/css/settings.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
```

example from functions.php file

```
function p24_scripts() {

wp_enqueue_style( 'p24-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );

wp_enqueue_style( 'p24-bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css', false );

wp_enqueue_style( 'p24-template', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/template.css', false );

wp_enqueue_style( 'p24-icomoon', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/icomoon.css', false );

wp_enqueue_style( 'p24-slick', get_template_directory_uri() . '/modules/slick/slick.css', false );

wp_enqueue_style( 'p24-slick-theme', get_template_directory_uri() . '/modules/slick/slick-theme.css', false );

wp_enqueue_style( 'p24-magnific-popup', get_template_directory_uri() . '/modules/Magnific-Popup/magnific-popup.css', false );

wp_enqueue_style( 'p24-modules-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/modules/vertical-timeline/css/style.css', false );

wp_enqueue_style( 'p24-pe-icon-7-stroke', get_template_directory_uri() . '/modules/revolution/fonts/pe-icon-7-stroke/css/pe-icon-7-stroke.css', false );

wp_enqueue_style( 'p24-font-awesome', get_template_directory_uri() . '/modules/revolution/fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css', false );

wp_enqueue_style( 'p24-settings', get_template_directory_uri() . '/modules/revolution/css/settings.css', false );

wp_enqueue_script( 'p24-jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/src/plugins/jquery-1.11.1.min.js', array(), '20151215', true );

if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
}
```

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'p24_scripts' );

Tell me why the styles do not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have answer ! I forget `<?php wp_head(); ?>` in header.php file

Answer (score 1):

Are you calling the function p24_scripts() after you have declared it?
Like so:

```
  add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'p24_scripts' );
```

In any case, check the console, another request might block your page load.
Try removing the google fonts request to see if this is blocking your page.

Comment: the console is clean, no bugs. Disabling fonts did not help.....  add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'p24_scripts' ); indicated at the end .still not working

Comment: You can find the status code of a request in the network tab of the console, if you click on the filename in the list you get to see the headers for that file. You can determine if they are loaded correctly. Also clear the cache of your browser when you update the code. Let me know if this helps you

Answer (score 1):

Your code is right.

Be sure to understand the difference with ...

```
// get path url from the main theme    
get_template_directory_uri()
```

and

```
// get path url from the child theme or active theme
get_stylesheet_uri()
```

Debug with your navigator console